# Error in writing SQL dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My code is like this

```
DECLARE @QueryText as NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @QueryText= 'select '"' + m.MACHINE_STREET + '"' AS MACHINE_LOCATION,
A.Country_Code AS Country,
(SELECT mibcp.REMARKS FROM tblMachineContact mibcp
where mibcp.mc_machine_pkey=m.pkey and mibcp.CONTACT_CATEGORY_PKEY=''IR'') AS REMARKS
                 from tblMachine m inner join tblAddress A
on m.Address_Pkey=A.Pkey
                 where m.Site= ''TSN'''

EXEC sp_Machine_Location,NULL,NULL,NULL,@QueryText
```

When running this dynamic query i am getting error at sub query.

```
(SELECT mibcp.REMARKS    
   FROM tblMachineContact mibcp
 WHERE mibcp.mc_machine_pkey=m.pkey    
   AND mibcp.CONTACT_CATEGORY_PKEY=''IR'') AS REMARKS.
```

How to avoid this ?

Comment: what kind of error you get?

Comment: also DBMS tag need

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Make sure that your inner query (SELECT mibcp.REMARKS... is getting single value for each row.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

That's probably cause your below quoted subquery part will return more than 1 record and you actually meant to fetch 1 record per row.

```
(SELECT mibcp.REMARKS FROM tblMachineContact mibcp
where mibcp.mc_machine_pkey=m.pkey and mibcp.CONTACT_CATEGORY_PKEY=''IR'') AS REMARKS
```

You can probably make your query like

```
select m.MACHINE_STREET AS MACHINE_LOCATION,
A.Country_Code AS Country,
mibcp.REMARKS 
FROM tblMachineContact mibcp
join tblMachine m on mibcp.mc_machine_pkey = m.pkey 
inner join tblAddress A on m.Address_Pkey = A.Pkey
where m.Site = 'TSN'
and mibcp.CONTACT_CATEGORY_PKEY = 'IR'
```

Comment: I need to fetch the contact_category_pkey=IR in subquery , so that it will return result if there are any values present otherwise it will return null. If i add this part in where condition it will only fetch the Contact_category as IR which is not my requirement. I will fetch many categories but i wanted remarks only for IR.

Comment: Any suggestion?